# Why string with datetime is string for .net framework but DateTime for .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, nswag

I'm using client's Swagger YAML file to generate models for one API where one property is a string type(ISO 8601) in swagger file`validUntil: type: string` and c# props is `public string ValidUntil { get; set; }` which were binding string data properly`"validUntil": "2022-07-12T07:03:45.428Z"` as string, but since the API migrated to `.net core` string value is being identified as `DateTime` and property is null.

Here is Swagger.yaml extract

```
 BaseClass:
  type: object
  title: BaseClass
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
    reference:
      type: string
    validUntil:
      type: string
    required:
    - id
    - validUntil
```

And this `validUntil` props in c#

```
 [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("validUntil", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string ValidUntil { get; set; }
```

I'm using NSwag to generate models.

```
..\..\packages\NSwag.MSBuild.11.20.1\tools\Win\NSwag.exe swagger2csclient /input:swagger.yaml /output:ApiModels.cs /GenerateClientClasses:false /namespace:Api.Model /GenerateDtoTypes:true /ClassStyle:Poco /GenerateJsonMethods:false /ArrayType:System.Collections.Generic.List /ArrayBaseType:System.Collections.Generic.List /GenerateExceptionClasses:false
```

I just want to understand the reasons behind this. It is something related to Newtonsoft json library?

Comment: Does the `validUntil` property in the yaml file have a `format` value?

Comment: No, only it has `type`.

Comment: So there's nothing in the yaml to indicate that it's a date, only a string? Can you [edit] your post with a [mre], including the yaml, how you're generating the C#, and the resulting C#?